# C# Windows form, MySQL Already running error

Tags: c#

I tried connecting a very simple program in C# and save it to database but I always get the exception error which is "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The connection is already open.'"

Here's my code:

```
    namespace sample
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public MySqlConnection connection;
    public Form1()
    { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { DBConnect dbc = new DBConnect();
       dbc.Insert();
        }
}
```

I tried closing the connection when the form start and non to avail.

and for the MySQL class in which I think where the error is:

```
    class DBConnect
{   private MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;

    public DBConnect()
    { Initialize(); }

    private void Initialize()
    {   server = "localhost";
        database = "csample";
        uid = "root";
        password = "1234";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);  }

    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
       try {  connection.Open();
              return true; }

        catch (MySqlException ex) {
            switch (ex.Number) {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator"); break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again"); break;
            }  MessageBox.Show("Failed!");  return false; }
    }

    private bool CloseConnection() {
     try
        {  connection.Close();
            return true; }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false; }
    }  
    public void Insert()
    {   
        string query = "INSERT INTO info values ('cedie','taguig'); ";
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {  MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         connection.Close();
         MessageBox.Show("CONNECTION OPENED \n SUCCESS!"); }

        else if (this.OpenConnection() == false) {
             MessageBox.Show("CONNECTION CLOSED \n FAILED!");
        }}}}
```

Don't mind the labels and textboxes as this program is just to execute the mysql

Comment: That's why it has been always recommended to use `using` statement in this scenarios.

Comment: *the MySQL class in which I think where the error is...*  NET reports exactly on which line such exceptions happen. if you dont even know where it happens get rid of that "helper" and write straight forward code to work with your DB.  Incidentally, the error in your title is not the same as the open mentioned in the post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also include the full stack trace of the exception.